# Remove first part of a path?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the first part of a path:

```
'/some/string/is/here' => '/string/is/here'
```

I've tried:

```
'/some/string/is/here'.split('/').slice(2).join('/') = string/is/here
```

But that removes the first slash too.

Is there a way to remove the first part of the path and retain the first slash?

Comment: regex or `'/' + '/some/string/is/here'.split('/').slice(2).join('/')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're guaranteed to have a leading slash, then just add the slash back:

```js
'/' + '/some/string/is/here'.split('/').slice(2).join('/')
```

If you're not guaranteed to have a leading slash, you can use regex:

```js
'/some/string/is/here'.match(/^\/?[^\/]+((?:\/[^\/]+)+)$/)[1]
// or
'/some/string/is/here'.replace(/^\/?[^\/]+/, "")
```

Alternatively, you can slice on the second slash:

```js
const str = '/some/string/is/here';
str.slice(str.indexOf("/", 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular Expression](https://javascript.info/regular-expressions) to replace the unwanted string part

```js
let str = '/some/string/is/here';
console.log(str.replace(/^\/\w+/, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```js
const myString = '/some/string/is/here';

console.log("/" + myString.replace(/^.+?[/]/, ''));
```